# Return 201 with location after saving using Spring Reactive Router

Tags: java, spring, rest, reactive

I'm using Spring Reactive with MongoDB to make a Rest API. Still getting acquainted with the functional paradigm, so I´m trying really hard to get things going. It´s an API about planets.

What I need is for the POST method to persist the planet to Mongo and add the generated ID to the 201 response location.

On a blog post the author creates an random UUID and sets it to the object to be persisted, but I don't think that's a production ready way of doing it.

This is what I have so far, it works well but without this requisite.

```
    public Mono<ServerResponse> addPlanet(ServerRequest serverRequest) {
    Mono<PlanetDTO> planetDTO = serverRequest.bodyToMono(PlanetDTO.class);
    return created(UriComponentsBuilder.fromPath("planet/").build().toUri())
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .body(fromPublisher(
                    planetDTO.map(p -> new Planet(p))
                            .flatMap(planetService::addPlanet), Planet.class));
```

And then the service code:

```
    public Mono<Planet> addPlanet(Planet planet) {
    return planetRepository.save(planet);
}
```

Does someone have a way of doing it functionally? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it! I will answer the question for anyone else who needs it, as there's still not many material on this framework yet.

```
    public Mono<ServerResponse> addPlanet(ServerRequest serverRequest) {
    Mono<PlanetDTO> planetDTO = serverRequest.bodyToMono(PlanetDTO.class);

    return planetDTO.map(p -> new Planet(p))
            .flatMap(planetService::addPlanet)
            .flatMap(p ->
                created(UriComponentsBuilder.fromPath("planet/" + p.getId()).build().toUri())
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .body(fromObject(new SWMessageDTO("Planet has been created!", 201)
                    ))
            );
```